# change color of enabled and disabled dates on asp calendar control

Tags: asp.net, colors, calendar

I have an asp:calendar control and  I want to know how to change the color of enabled and disabled dates of the calendar control...

on the pictures i have attached, the enabled dates colors are black, and the disabled dates colors are white

I want to interchange the two

**enabled dates = white**

**disabled dates = black**

[image]

Comment: On which condition you have made date enable and disable?

Comment: protected void Calendar1_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e) // disable future dates on calendar control 
        {
            if (e.Day.Date > DateTime.Today)
            {
                e.Day.IsSelectable = false;
            }
        }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I understand please try following code in code behind file.

```
protected void Calendar1_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e) // disable future dates on calendar control
        {
            if (e.Day.Date > DateTime.Today)
            {
                e.Day.IsSelectable = false;
                e.Cell.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
            }
            else
            {
                e.Cell.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            }
        }
```